# Webpack not recognizing npm module that starts with '@'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui, babeljs, babel-loader

I am trying to move from a CRA app to using webpack, but having trouble with the loaders.

I have npm modules that start with '@', including but not limited to @material-ui/core/styles.
Removal of this '@' is not an option, I need to figure out how to get around this error.

The error I am seeing it this:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@connect/nav/lib/Canvas/index.js 116:17

Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (116:17)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
| "use strict";
> module.exports = @material-ui/core/styles;
```

My webpack.config.js is

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: [path.join(__dirname, 'src'), 'node_modules'],
    alias: {
      react: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules', 'react'),
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.svg$/,
        use: {
            loader: 'svg-url-loader',
            options: {
                encoding: 'base64'
            }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, 
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '/public/assets/[name].[ext]'
        }
    }
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      template: './public/index.html',
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  }
};
```

Using the following packages:

```
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
```

Comment: May you share code of ./node_modules/@connect/nav/lib/Canvas/index.js file?

Comment: its a compiled file thats not easily readable as its in node_modules but heres the important parts:

```(() => { // webpackBootstrap
/******/  var __webpack_modules__ = ({
/***/ "./src/Canvas/Canvas.js":
/*!******************************!*\
  !*** ./src/Canvas/Canvas.js ***!
  \******************************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, exports, __webpack_require__) => {

"use strict";
eval("Object.define........")

"use strict";
module.exports = @material-ui/core/styles;
```